# ASP MVC 5 and Web Api 2 can't view page on complete links

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have 2 controllers, 1 is an MVC and 1 is Web Api 2.
The latter seems to work correctly, but the first can't display HTML pages only when I write the full address.

This is my simple `RouteConfig.cs`

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}",
        defaults: new {
            controller = "Base",
            action = "Main"
        }
    );
)
```

Let's take the default as example, so controller is `Base` and action is `Main`, the code is straightforward

```
public ActionResult Main() {
    return View();
}
```

http://localhost/miApps --> work and display content of /View/Base/Main
http://localhost/miApps/Base --> work and display content of /View/Base/Main
http://localhost/miApps/Base/Main --> doesn't work, the error is

> {"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost/miApps/Base/Main'.","MessageDetail":"No type was found that matches the controller named 'Base'."}

---

I post also `WebApiConfig.cs`, maybe there is an interaction?

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}",
        defaults: new {
            //id = RouteParameter.Optional
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: That url what you mentioned in the error and what you posted as not working are not same. Can you update the question with correct details?

Comment: Change your route to - `url: "miApps/{controller}/{action}"` for your `default` route and let me know if it works.

Comment: It doesn't work. `miApps` is the name of IIS application, shouldn't be included in any route config files, right?

Comment: Yes, you shouldn't. I thought it is the way you want to make request to your endpoints. So in this case, I dont see any problem with your routes, there might be something else which you have in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The route to API controllers should have a prefix (usually '/api/') in order to make a distinction from ordinary controllers.

try updating your `WebApiConfig.cs` to this:

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
        defaults: new {
            //id = RouteParameter.Optional
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: It seems the only viable way. I added a prefix in Api controller, then I added a `Route` decoration removing the needing of the prefix, so in `WebApiConfig.cs` i changed to `routeTemplate: "API/{controller}/{action}"`, then in my controller named `Rest` in action named `GetName` I added the attribute `[Route("Rest/GetName/{name?}")]`. This is not very practical, I hope there is a better solution

Comment: You could use `[RoutePrefix]` attribute on your API controller and then use `[Route]` on action methods only with the arguments. e.g. `[Route("{name}")]`  [link](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)